# render d3 linear nice scale with whole numbers only

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently use `d3.scale.linear().nice()` to render my y axis. However, this is sometimes an issue when the values are only whole numbers eg. 1 - 5 but the ticks are rendered 1-5 in 0.5 increments. Is there any way to specify whole numbers only in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tickFormat` method.

```
d3.scale.linear().nice().tickFormat(d3.format("d"));
```